# Actionscript quiz: draw circle around the option chosen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

With this function, multiple choice questions and answers  are displayed. But I want  a circle  around the option's letter like this http://www.cambridge.org/other_files/Flash_apps/inuse/EVUElementaryTest/EVUElementaryIndex.htm when user clicked an "answer option" of A, B, C, D, E.  Is this possible?

```
            function showQuestions(index,limit ):void{

                var mainContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
                mainContainer.name="qContainer";
                //mainContainer.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
                mainContainer.graphics.drawRect(0,0,700, 500);
                mainContainer.x=(stage.stageWidth - 700) /2;
                mainContainer.y=(stage.stageHeight - 500) /2;
                addChild(mainContainer);



                for (i=index; i < (index+limit); i++) {


                    var questionTextField = new TextField();
                    mainContainer.addChild(questionTextField);

                    questionTextField.text=i + "  " +  qnodes[i].QUESTION.text();
                    questionTextField.name=i;
                    questionTextField.width=400;
                    questionTextField.x= 0;
                    questionTextField.y=i%limit * 100;

                    var numberOfAnswers= (qnodes[i].OPT.length())
                    var j:Number;


                    for (j=0; j < numberOfAnswers; j++) {

                        var answerTextField = new TextField();
                        mainContainer.addChild(answerTextField);


                        var optionLetterMc = new MovieClip();


                        optionLetterMc.name="Answer"+i;
                        optionLetterMc.x=((j%3) * 250)   ;
                        optionLetterMc.y= (i%limit * 100) + 20 + (int(j / 3) * 20) ;
                        optionLetterMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnAnswerSelected);
                        optionLetterMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveStudentAnswer);
                        mainContainer.addChild(optionLetterMc);

                        var optLetterTextField = new TextField();
                        optionLetterMc.addChild(optLetterTextField);
                        optLetterTextField.text=optionLetters[j];
                        optLetterTextField.name=i;




                        answerTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
                        answerTextField.x=((j%3) * 250) + 20 ;
                        answerTextField.y=  (i%limit * 100) + 20 + (int(j / 3) * 20) ;
                        answerTextField.text=qnodes[i].OPT[j].text();

                    }
                }

                    var btn:Button = new Button();
                    btn.label = "Next";
                    btn.x=(stage.stageWidth - 300) /2;
                    btn.y=500;
                    mainContainer.addChild(btn);
                    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextQuestions);

            }
```

UPDATE: Changes I did: I created **optionLetterMc** and then I added optionTextField inside.  They are named as **optionLetterMc.name="Answer"+i;**

Here is your part (changed a bit).

```
 var mSelectedAnswer:MovieClip;

 Mouse.hide();
 Pencil.mouseEnabled = false;

 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, OnMouseMove);
 //Answer1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnAnswerSelected);

 function OnMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
 Pencil.x = stage.mouseX;
 Pencil.y = stage.mouseY;
  }


  function OnAnswerSelected(e:MouseEvent):void
  {

mSelectedAnswer = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
DeselectAll();
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, OnMouseMove);
Pencil.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, OnAnswerEnterFrame);
Pencil.gotoAndPlay("Draw_Circle");
//trace(mSelectedAnswer.name);
}

function OnAnswerEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
if(e.target.currentFrame == e.target.totalFrames)
{

    trace(mSelectedAnswer.name);
    mSelectedAnswer.gotoAndStop("Selected");
    Pencil.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, OnAnswerEnterFrame);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, OnMouseMove);
}
}

function DeselectAll():void
{
mSelectedAnswer.gotoAndStop("Normal");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make an animation of pencil movement and label the animation accordingly in the pencil `MovieClip` and stop it on the first frame. Then you'd just change it's coordinates to needed ones and do something like this:

```
Pencil_MovieClip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onPencilEnterFrame);
Pencil_MovieClip.gotoAndPlay("DrawCircle");

function onPencilEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
{
    if(Pencil_MovieClip.currentFrame == Pencil_MovieClip.totalFrames) 
    {
        DeselectAllAnswers();
        ClickedAnswer_MovieClip.gotoAndStop("selected");
        Pencil_MovieClip.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onPencilEnterFrame);
    }
}
```

You'll need an enter frame event listener to react on pencil animation finish. When the animation finishes you move your selectable answer `MovieClip` to another frame labeled "selected", which has that circle graphic.

`DeselectAllAnswers` function would just say to all the selectable answers to go to default frame, where there is no selection circle.

I consider that ClickedAnswer_MovieClip is the `MovieClip` of selectable answer which was clicked.

EDIT: All this code I wrote is the selectable answer `MovieClip` click handler by the way.

EDIT 2: If my description wasn't enough here's an example I put together: [LINK](http://db.tt/83QwMsN8)

Comment: I could not catch your approach. Here I tried something more simple (without animation). Could you please see update.

Comment: I'll give you an example in a second.

Comment: @mustafa I've updated my answer with a link to an example. I think my approach is easier to change and customize later on, so take a look.

Comment: I can not open your file since I am using CS5.

Comment: I'll convert it in a second. @mustafa I've renewed the link.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The result is very nice. Could you please advice me how I can add it to my code.

Comment: I think I should use moviClip instead of "optLetterTextField" text fields for the option letters. Correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22339/discussion-between-gio-and-mustafa)

Comment: I tried to integrate animation into my code but I could not manage perfectly.  Circle does not appear on option letter. I create the "optionLetterMc" on the fly. so I do not know how to create frame and label for dynamicly created MCs. I updated code please see it

Comment: Then make a symbol of the circle in Flash and export it for ActionScript. Then you can create and add new circles when needed and remove them when not needed anymore, or you could switch the visibility of those circles, which will be added in your answerMCs.